# sonarQube scan bug - make field transient or serializable for List

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, serializable, transient

Fields in a "Serializable" class should either be transient or serializable for HashSet and ArrayList

The class implements java.io.Serializable but contains a member of Set type.
But the implementation of Set is HashSet. This is serializable.
Still, SonarQube scan is flagging as a critical issue

@JGlobalMap

```
public class RequestAccess implements java.io.Serializable {   
   private Set<Escouter> escouters = new HashSet(0);
   private List supportTower= new ArrayList();
   public Set<Escouter> getEscouters() {
        return this.escouters;
    }
   public void setEscouters(Set<Escouter> escouters) {
        this.escouters = escouters;
    }
   public List getSupportTower() {
        return supportTower;
    }
   public void setSupportTower(List supportTower) {
        this.supportTower = supportTower;
    }
}
```

Comment: What objects are going into your `supportTower` list? SonarQube can't guess since you've not applied generics, so don't know if the list contents will be serializable or not.

Comment: SupportTower is a DTO and some members are String types and some are Set Types

Comment: If you're referring to the line `private List supportTower= new ArrayList();`, then you need to add type arguments (e.g. private List<SupportTower> supportTower= new ArrayList<>();`) to tell SonarQube what's going in the list. If `SupportTower` than contains further `Collection`s then you'll also need to apply generics to them